# Storing generics temporarily

Tags: c#, .net, generics, visual-studio-2013

I was wondering in this scenario, if there is any better way of doing things without creating a lot of custom classes for something that should be "generic".
Can there be any trouble with the dynanmic with this?

For the lambda version, it will create garbage to reference the updateMethod and the values, right?

For the dynamic, is there anything bad about it other than a slight decrease in performance and no intellisense and strong typing?

Storing the values and the updateMethod as objects, and the type of the TVal to cast the objects back to their original type later, feels messy and a lot of casting here and there.

```
public class Test
{
    dynamic Values;
    dynamic UpdateMethod;

    public void Update<TVal>(TVal[] values, Action<int, TVal> updateMethod) 
        where TVal : class
    {
        // lambda
        Parallel.For(0, values.Length, (i) => { updateMethod(i, values[i]); });

        // vs

        // dynamic
        Values = values;
        UpdateMethod = updateMethod;

        Parallel.For(0, values.Length, Work);
    }

    void Work(int i)
    {
        UpdateMethod(i, Values[i]);
    }
}
```

And, additionally, why exactly doesn't this work.
`Action<int, dynamic> UpdateMethod = updateMethod;`

Why I ask these questions? Curiosity and always good to expand knowledge, why, if it is good and or bad.
+ how would one search for this, if someone else has posted it online, I can't find any search parameters.

Sorry if the title, or the questions don't fit stackoverflow, I don't know where else to ask.

Comment: You should try to ask only a question at a time, otherwise it's pretty hard to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda approach is the way to go.

Your other approach stores "Values" or "UpdateMethod" in member variables, which unnecessarily increases the scope and lifetime of those variables.  So "values" might not get garbage collected because your Test class is holding on to it beyond the end of "Update".  It also makes the code no longer thread safe.  Suppose two threads try to call "Update" with different parameters, simultaneously.  They will each overwrite the "Values" and possibly call the wrong "UpdateMethod."  And yes, dynamic is less efficient.  Very much so.

I am unsure what you mean when you asked about "garbage to reference the updateMethod and the values, right?" Are you concerned that it will create temporaries?  If so, using dynamic will not prevent temporary values.  And garbage collection makes eliminating temporaries fairly efficient.

Last thought: You may find this valueable:  [Eric Lippert's thoughts on Enumerable.ForEach.](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/02/eric-lippert-on-the-decision-to-omit-enumerable-foreach/)  It isn't exactly what you are doing, but kinda similar.

Comment: I was aware of the threading issue. If I went that route, I would have put a lock inside the update method, but then it would go further to deadlocking if the work called the Update once more.
Thanks for saying it outright that the lambda is the way to go, having a strong foundation helps, but its also good to be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the valies and method as class fields, a cleaner method is to make the *class* generic instead of just the *method*:

```
public class Test<TVal>
        where TVal : class
{
    TVal[] Values;
    Action<int, TVal> UpdateMethod;

    public void Update(TVal[] values, Action<int, TVal> updateMethod) 

    {
        // lambda
        Parallel.For(0, values.Length, (i) => { updateMethod(i, values[i]); });

        // OR

        Values = values;
        UpdateMethod = updateMethod;

        Parallel.For(0, values.Length, Work);
    }

    void Work(int i)
    {
        UpdateMethod(i, Values[i]);
    }
}
```

However there's nothing wrong with just using a lambda:

```
public void Update<TVal>(TVal[] values, Action<int, TVal> updateMethod) 
    where TVal : class
{
    // lambda
    Parallel.For(0, values.Length, (i) => { updateMethod(i, values[i]); });
}
```

I don't know what you mean about "creating garbage" - if you're worried that the lambda will introduce a memory leak - don't worry about it until you can *measure* a problem.

Comment: As far as I know, managed code can't create a memmory leak, unless it calls code that isn't managed. 
The thing that I am worried about, is that for a realtime application, the garbage can cause small spikes in the performance, but like they say, don't make premature optimizations, but it doesn't hurt to know why and what can be done in the future, if there is a problem.